# how to konw a package global installed full path by pnpm?

Tags: npm, pnpm

how to konw a package global installed full path by pnpm?
I have tried `pnpm store path`.
that was not precise enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `where <app>` to list paths of app if using windows command shell.

```
# example
where vue
```

[image]